# How do I reference a choice list in django template?

Tags: django, template-engine

I have the following in my django model:

```
PRIORITY = (
    (1, 'Low'),
    (2, 'Normal'),
    (3, 'High'),
)
```

Obviously the entry associated with this is storing the integer.  In my template however I would like to show the priority in human-readable format.  How exactly do I accomplish this?

My template:

```
{% for x in items %}
{{ x }} (added on {{ x.create_date }})<br>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ x.id }}` would be the priority ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: good question, I was looking for the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Really, the "priority" with name and ID is a self-invented kind of object that you've thought up.  If you just make this a Priority model and treat it as such it will all work the way it should.  It's because you're trying to avoid using the system that you're having trouble.

Comment: I'm still learning django, so learning mostly by example.  

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: sorry but to be sincere this is really an useless, unhelpful and stupid answer.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you have correctly set the [choices](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) option when defining your model, Django automatically creates helper functions to display the names for you. See the documentation on [extra instance methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#extra-instance-methods) for details.

If your model instance is `x` and your attribute that stores the priority is `priority`, then in your template you would use:

```
{{ x.get_priority_display }}
```